# How do i make a command in python which can be used by the user throughout the python game?

Tags: python

The title might not help much, but it was the only way i could really explain it in a sum of a "sentence".

Here's my query:

I'm new to python, yes, new.

We are making this **text adventure** game in python. The character ("user") in the game should be able to see their "xp" in the replit console when the game asks "do you want to see your xp?". The user will reply yes, so it will show. How do i make it so that you can see your xp throughout the game and if a monster or something **takes or increases** your xp. How would it(the xp) be edited? Would it be using the .append command?

The same goes with the backpack in the code below. Would it be .append("object here")?

Here's my code so far

```
import time
#inventory/statistics
backpack = ("flashlight", "2 water bottles", "Am apple", "A blanket")

#the beginning, linked to the last code
name = input("Welcome to Medolxa adventurer! Please type your name, to begin this mysterious adventure: \n")
time.sleep(1)
print("Great, welcome to Medolxa",name,"!")
time.sleep(1)

#this is the second part of the game
def main():
    print("Hint: Use these wisely, your HP will decrease any time if used insufficiently, your HP will be mentioned throughout the game,or maybe ")
    time.sleep(1)

#the introduction to the game
def intro():
    print("/  \    /  \ ____ |  |   ____  ____   _____  ____ ")
    print("\   \/\/   // __ \|  | _/ ___\/  _ \ /     \_/ __ ")
    print(" \        /\  ___/|  |_\  \__(  <_> )  Y Y  \  ___/ ")
    print("  \__/\  /  \___  >____/\___  >____/|__|_|  /\___>")
    print("Loading...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You leave the boat and head onto the wet  land, the others follow just behind you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("You seem to be in the middle of nowhere, the grass is wet")
    time.sleep(1)
    inventory = input("You have a backpack, would you like to see what is inside?: (y/n) \n")
    if inventory == "n":
     print("alrighty")
     main()
    elif inventory == "y":
     print(backpack, "this is all you have right now!")
     main()



#beginning (to make the code work, this is the main menu)
start = True
while start==True:
 yes = "y"
 no = "n"
 game = input("This game is a horror, mysterious gane, would you like to continue?: (y/n)  \n")
 if game == yes:
    print("Alrighty, let's go!")
    start = False
    intro()
 elif game == no:
    print("Game has ended, come back once you're ready!")
    start = False
```

**should i make a file and then do "file.append("object here")? for the backpack and for the xp i'd do file.append(12) etc and then do file.read?**

Comment: For your XP just use a global variable (defined outside of a function) which is an integer `XP = 0`, then when something happens which changes your XP, add or subtract from that variable. As for the backpack, just create a list `backpack = ['flashlight', 'food']`, then you can add with `backpack.append('water')` and remove with `backpack.remove('water')`.

Comment: makes sense, thanks!